# 401 when receiving participants from the server, how to decide?

Tags: php, discord

I want the site to display the number of participants from the server on the site, I kind of passed all the headers with a token, but I still get a 401 error

Here is my code:
`

```
<?php $json_options = [ "http" => [ "method" => "GET", "header" => "Authorization: token" ] ];
$json_context = stream_context_create($json_options); 
$json_get = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/SERVER-ID/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context); 
$json_decode = json_decode($json_get, true);

echo count($json_decode); ?>
```

`

I tried to recreate the token on the application page

Comment: Please format your code properly and add line breaks after each operation. It will make the code way more readable. There's no bonus points for writing it all in one line, rather the opposite.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it